# Would it be possible to make a Gun type nuclear bomb using Isotopically pure Plutonium-239

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, explosions

I know that it's normally not possible to make a gun type nucelar bomb using plutonium due to high rates of spontaneous fission.
But that's primarily due to the plutonium 240.
If you instead used ONLY plutonium 239, would it then be possible to make a Gun type nuclear bomb.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-239 - "239Pu has a higher probability for fission than 235U and a larger number of neutrons produced per fission event, so it has a smaller critical mass. Pure 239Pu also has a reasonably low rate of neutron emission due to spontaneous fission (10 fission/s·kg), making it feasible to assemble a mass that is highly supercritical before a detonation chain reaction begins."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a Plutonium gun-type atomic bomb really "impossible"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196732/is-a-plutonium-gun-type-atomic-bomb-really-impossible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good source is B. Cameron Reed's paper on ["Predetonation probability of a fission-bomb core](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.3367757) in the American Journal of Physics. To quote from the text:

> For a 6.2 kg core
> of pure Pu-239, an assembly time of 200 $\mu$s yields a nopredetonation
> probability of 99.2% (S=0).

where the parameter S is the number of scattering events for neutrons. S=0 is the worst case for predetonation probability.